# Argument of type 'IAulasAdicionais[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: react, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

Opa, estou com este problema no meu codigo o qual não estou conseguindo solucionar, segue abaixo o meu codigo espero que possam me ajudar!!!

Dados mocados:

```
"AulasAdicionais": [
    {
      "Periodo": "1",
      "HorarioInicio": "2021-01-19T07:30:00-0300",
      "HorarioTermino": "2021-01-19T08:30:00-0300",
      "IdDisciplina": "396",
      "DescricaoDisciplina": "Matemática",
      "DescricaoReduzidaDisciplina": "Mat",
      "DescricaoTurno": "Manhã",
      "IdEstabelecimento": "43",
      "DescricaoEstabelecimento": "Colégio Correio Lima",
      "TipoSituacaoHorario": "Normal"
    }
  ]
```

Meu service

```
export interface IAulasAdicionais {
  Periodo: string;
  HorarioInicio: string;
  HorarioTermino: string;
  IdDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoReduzidaDisciplina: string;
  DescricaoTurno: string;
  IdEstabelecimento: string;
  DescricaoEstabelecimento: string;
  TipoSituacaoHorario: string;
}

export interface IAgendaAulas {  
  AulasAdicionais: IAulasAdicionais[];

}

const getAgendaAulas = async (dataAula: string ) : Promise<IAgendaAulas[] | undefined> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await Api().get<IAgendaAulas[]>(
      `/agenda-aulas?DataAula=${dataAula}`
    );
    if (data) {
      return data;
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

Este e meu TSX:

```
interface IAgendasAulasProps {
  aulasAdicionais: IAulasAdicionais[];
}

export const AulasAdicionaisRecuperacao: React.FC<IAgendasAulasProps> = ({
  aulasAdicionais,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [aulaAdicionais, setAulasAdicionais] = useState<
    IAulasAdicionais[]
  >();

  useEffect(() => {
    AgendaTurmaService.getAgendaAulas(aulasAdicionais "O problema está aqui" ).then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        setAulasAdicionais(data "e aqui");
      } else {
        setAulasAdicionais([]);
      }
    });
  }, [aulasAdicionais]);

{aulaAdicionais?.map((horario, horarioIndex) => (
        <>
          <Grid container spacing={2} key={horarioIndex}>
            <Grid item lg={2}>
              <Box margin={1}>
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                  <Box marginTop={2} marginLeft={1}>
                    <ClassIcon color="primary" style={{ fontSize: 90 }} />
                    <Box display="flex" marginTop={-10} marginLeft={12}>
                      <Typography>{horario?.DescricaoDisciplina}</Typography>
                    </Box>
                  </Box>
                </Paper>
              </Box>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </>
      ))}
```

vou postar um print do que está ocorrendo para facilitar o entendimento
[image: Erro 1]

[image: Erro 2]

Comment: Aparentemente o problema está onde assinalou mas seria bastante mais elucidativo se mostrasse o código dessa funções. Muito provavelmente a função `getAgendaAulas` devolve um objeto com a propriedade `data` que é um array do tipo `IAgendaAulas`, Depois, está a passar esse valor `data` para uma função `setAulasAdicionais` que recebe um array do tipo `IAulasAdicionas` como argumento.

Comment: Ler código "em linha" num comentário?!? Por favor edite a sua pergunta e adicione este código lá (e já agora também o de `setAulasAdicionais`).

Comment: Bem desculpe, mas ambos já estão na minha questão!

Comment: Ok. Para fazer o set das aulas adicionais, experimente alterar de `setAulasAdicionais(data);` para `setAulasAdicionais(data.AulasAdicionais);`. Quanto ao `getAgendaAulas`, não sei ao certo quais as necessidades da implementação mas penso que exista algum erro na definição da função, pois ela espera que o argumento seja do tipo `string`.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda, porem ao tentar acessar as propriedades de data ele n me retorna nada. Existe outro modo de eu acessar essas propriedades?

Comment: Se fizer debug ou até mesmo colocar um `console.log` depois de fazer a chamada a `AgendaTurmaService.getAgendaAulas`, qual o conteúdo de `data`?

Comment: [Retorno](https://ibb.co/1QPhGck) ele n me retorna nada! mas era para conter as propriedades de IAulasAdicionais

Comment: Terá de fazer debugging para encontrar o problema. Experimente verificar se está a entrar no `catch`. Verifique também se a chamada à API está correta.

Comment: [Debuggin](https://ibb.co/yqrC4G0) no meu console de debug me retorna isto

Comment: Por favor coloque um `console.log`na linha 46 (antes de chamar `setAulasAdicionais`) e depois mostre o output.

Comment: Coloquei o console.log(data) e o retorno e [este](https://ibb.co/JRwj9t2)

Answer (score 0):

amigo, a função `AgendaTurmaService#getAgendaAulas` espera uma string como argumento e vc esta passando um array de objetos.

Pelo codigo q vc compartilhou:

```
const getAgendaAulas = async (dataAula: string )
```

vc tem que passar a uma string que seria a data na qual vc deseja obter as aulas no servidor.

O problema esta nas props do seu component `AulasAdicionaisRecuperacao`, como prop vc espera receber os dados das aulas, mas internamente vc busca esses dados.

Suas opcoes sao.

1. fazer essa busca de dados nesse componente (`AulasAdicionaisRecuperacao`) e passar apenas a data selecionada. ou
2. onde vc usa esse componente fazer a busca dos dados no servidor e apenas passar os dados para esse, e remover essa chamada da de API.